# how to make div fixed and ot move upon window resize

Tags: css

I have divs as follows:

upon resizing the window, the table in div3 is moving under the text of div1.  How can I make it such a way that upon rezing the window, the table remains just next to the text and it doesn`t get moved below the text nor do they get resized.

```
     <div id="Div1" >
<text> </text>
       </div>
    <div id="Div2" >
        <div id="Div3" > 
            <table> </table>
        </div>
        <div  id="Div4" >
        </div>
        <div  id="Div5" >
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

css style

```
    #Div2
{
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: You can use position: absolute and fix the size of you table and the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should add width to `Div2`

```
#Div2
{
    float: left;
    overflow: auto;
    width:300px;    
}
```

And I don't know what css rules applied to Div1, it can be important.

Comment: Even setting the width doesn`t stop the table from going below the text.

Comment: @learning Do you want Div2 to be left/right of Div1?  If so, you should make Div1 float

Comment: the table should be on the right of the text and never to move even after the resize of the window

Answer (score 0):

using float: left

for the table, if you like to make it to the left of the text.